# groupby - aggregate - groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

```
Category | Unit | ID | Time | isReq
  1         A     x1    t1      0 
  1         A     x1    t2      0 
  1         A     x1    t3      0 
  1         A     x1    t4      0
  1         B     x2    t5      1 
  1         B     x2    t6      0 
  1         B     x2    t7      0
```

I am trying to find the unique number of IDs per category and unit, as well as the mean time duration for them. The final result should look like :-

```
Category | Unit | ID_count |            time:diff
   1        A        1         mean_time_to_completion for all ids in category and unit
```

There can be multiple `ID`s under a given `Category` and `Unit`. 
How can I go ahead  with the data that I have to get the result? I can independently get the unique `ID`s groupped by `Category` and `Unit`, but I'm having difficulty in getting all the fields in one query.

EDIT:- I've managed to perform the necessary operation the following way  : -

```
 df1.groupby(['Category','Unit','ID'])['Time'].agg(['first','last']).diff(axis = 1).iloc[:,-1].reset_index().groupby(['Category','Unit']).agg({'ID' : 'count','last' : pd.Series.mean})
```

I now am trying to calculate the contribution of each `ID` as a perc  of total `isReq` count in the same query as above. Any helpful suggestions will be welcome

Comment: `df.groupby(['Category','Unit']).agg({'ID':'count', 'Time':np.ptp})`?

Comment: Please see the edit to the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
df.groupby(['Category', 'Unit']).agg(ID_count=('ID','nunique'), time_diff=('Time', 'mean'))
```

Comment: I need to calculate the mean of time duration for every combination of category and unit. For that, I need to group by ID and find the duration for each ID , and then find the mean duration and total number of IDs for each category and unit

Comment: The groupby will ensure that you get values corresponding to all combinations of `Category` and `Unit`. In case you need the count of unique ID's for every combination of category and units, use `nunique` otherwise replace it with `count`. The `mean` function in `time_diff=('Time', 'mean')` will ensure that you get mean of `Time` for every combination of `Category` and `Unit`.